# SQL join query returning row for each matching ASOC

Tags: sql, join

Suppose there are 3 tables: BOOKS, TAGS and ASOC

```
+----------+  +----------+  +----------+
|BOOKS     |  |TAGS      |  |ASOC      |
+----------+  +----------+  +----------+
|book_id   |  |tag_id    |  |book_id   |
|book_name |  |tag       |  |tag_id    |
|...       |  +----------+  +----------+
+----------+
```

Hopefully the use/intent in this example is obvious..

I want to query books that match a certain set of tags. So I try something like:

```
SELECT B.book_name
FROM   BOOKS B
,      TAGS T
,      ASOC A
WHERE  B.book_id = A.book_id
AND    T.tag_id = A.tag_id
AND    (T.tag = 'Classic' OR T.tag = 'Fiction')
```

The undesirable result that I'm getting is that each book is being listed multiple times, once for each tag ASOC entry. I just want the unique list of books that match. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MSDN [Article on removing duplicate rows with distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) SQL Fiddle of the code [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a39a/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a39a/1)

Comment: You could add the DISTINCT clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change `SELECT B.book_name` to `SELECT DISTINCT B.book_name`; however, it might be better to write:

```
SELECT book_name
  FROM books
 WHERE book_id IN
        ( SELECT book_id
            FROM asoc
           WHERE tag_id IN
                  ( SELECT tag_id
                      FROM tags
                     WHERE tag IN ('Classic', 'Fiction')
                  )
        )
;
```

where the structure of the query makes clearer what you really want. (I suggest trying both on realistic data; it's possible that one will perform much better than the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` to get a unique list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.book_name
FROM   BOOKS B
,      TAGS T
,      ASOC A
WHERE  B.book_id = A.book_id
AND    T.tag_id = A.tag_id
AND    (T.tag = 'Classic' OR T.tag = 'Fiction')
```

As a further enhancement, that last line can be rewritten to be slightly more readable:

```
AND    T.tag IN ('Classic', 'Fiction')
```

You can also make the JOINs more efficient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.book_name
FROM   BOOKS B
       INNER JOIN ASOC A on B.book_id = A.book_id
       INNER JOIN TAGS T on A.tag_id = T.tag_id
WHERE  T.tag IN ('Classic', 'Fiction')
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to "match a certain set of tags".  If I take this to mean "all the tags", then this is a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using aggregation:

```
SELECT B.book_name
FROM   BOOKS B join
       ASOC A
       on B.book_id = A.book_id
       TAGS T
       on T.tag_id = A.tag_id
group by B.book_name
having sum(case when t.tag = 'Classic' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.tag = 'Fiction' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of occurrences of each tag.  The comparisons require that *both* tags be in the set.

By the way, if you want books that match *either* tag, just change the `and` to an `or`.  The reason I like this approach is because the query is quite flexible.  You can express many different conditions just by changing the `having` clause.

I also changed your query to use ANSI standard join syntax.  You should learn to write queries using this syntax.